# CMAKE default value for options doesn't work

Tags: cmake

If I have the following line.  Then I would expect `TEST_OPTION` to be set to `ON` by default.

```
option( TEST_OPTION "A test option" ON)
```

When I test it, it doesn't seem to be `ON` by default.  To test, I am compiling a simple application:

```
int main() {

  #ifdef TEST_OPTION
    #error "TEST_OPTION encountered"
  #endif 
  return 0;
}
```

I also have a simple CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(test)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

option( TEST_OPTION "A test option" ON)

if(TEST_OPTION)
  target_compile_definitions(test PRIVATE TEST_OPTION)
endif(TEST_OPTION)
```

If I try to compile with `$ cmake && cmake --build .`, I would expect to encounter the compile error, but I don't!  If I replace `option( TEST_OPTION ... )` with `set(TEST_OPTION ON)`, then I get the compile error that I expected.

Can someone explain why `option()` doesn't set the option to the default value by default?

Comment: You test code should work. Did you start from an empty build directory?

Comment: Wow, you're right!  It was that the CMakeCache didn't get refreshed.  It required me to delete the CMake cache, then it triggered the error as expected.

Comment: Same issue, even if I delete everything and rerun cmake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution: 
The cmake cache doesn't seem to refresh when you change an option's default.  Therefor, by first constructing it with "OFF" selected, the "ON" option was completely ignored.  To solve this I just had to delete the generated cmake artifacts and run `cmake` again.

Comment: There must exist a better way than deleting the cache. I just stumbled over the same issue. The question should be, how-to override the default value.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, you can use `cmake -UTEST_OPTION`. This argument allows for globbing too. In my case, I fixed this by updating cached arguments with the `cmake -UCONFIG_BUILD_* ...` where `CONFIG_BUILD_TESTS` defaults to `ON`.

Comment: Wanted to add that it does happened for me as well and -UTEST_OPTION (my option variable was also called TEST_OPTION) helped. What it exactly does is CMakeCache  entry emoval which for me solved this problem.

Comment: As for reason why I encountered it in first place - I use Visual Studio Code with CMake support extension which on change to CMakeLists.txt, saves entries in CMakeCache if they are not there yet and if they are, it doesn't update cache with new value itself. Clean doesnt work with that either. In order to change default option, I need to either run cmake with -UOPTION_NAME or simply remove CMakeCache and run cmake.